# Remove tabs starting with expression with R shiny tabset and javascript through plotly

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, tabs

So I have a graph using `plotly` which has JS code to `setInputValue`. Now that input value will depend on which bar of my bar graph is clicked, and it is different.

I want to make it so that every time a tab is already open from the interactive graph, trying to open another tab (using the interactive graph), will remove the previous tab and append the new one.

Right now I can't seem to remove the tab, it keeps adding the tabs

```
js <- '
function(el, x) {
  el.on("plotly_click", function(eventData) {
    var point = eventData.points[0];
    var MPA = point.text;
    
    var pattern = /Month: (\\d{4}-\\d{2}).*Main Practice Area: ([^<]+)/;
    var matches = MPA.match(pattern);
    
    if (matches !== null) {
      var yearMonth = matches[1];
      var mainPracticeArea = matches[2];
      MPA = "Month: " + yearMonth + ", MPA: " + mainPracticeArea;
    }
    
    Shiny.setInputValue("MPA", MPA);
  });
}'

#more code
#within the server

observeEvent(input$MPA, {
    
    tabset_id <- "tabset"
    
    # Check if there is a previously opened tab
    if (!is.null(input[[tabset_id]])) {
      # Get the identifier of the previous tab
      previous_tab <- names(input[[tabset_id]])
      
      # Remove the previous tab
      removeTab(inputId = tabset_id, target = previous_tab)
    }

    #i also tried something like
    # existing_tabs <- names(input$tabset)
    # 
    # # Find tabs that start with "Month"
    # tabs_to_remove <- grep("^Month", existing_tabs)
    # 
    # # Remove tabs that start with "Month"
    # for (tab in tabs_to_remove) {
    #   removeTab("tabset", tab)
    # }
    
    # Create a new tab with the title set to input[["MPA"]]
    new_tab <- tabPanel(
      title = input[["MPA"]],
      print("heloo")
    )
    
    # Append the new tab
    appendTab(
      tabset_id,
      new_tab,
      select = TRUE
    )
  })

 output$stackedBarPlot <- renderPlotly({
    excess <- excess_supply()
    
    # Filter the data based on the selected Main Practice Areas
    selected_areas <- input$mainPracticeArea
    if (!is.null(selected_areas)) {
      excess_filtered <- filter(excess, `Main Practice Area` %in% selected_areas)
    } else {
      excess_filtered <- excess  # If no areas selected, use all data
    }
    
    # Calculate the Overall Excess by summing Excess by Month for the selected practice areas
    overall_excess <- excess_filtered %>%
      group_by(Month) %>%
      summarize(Overall_Excess = sum(Excess, na.rm = TRUE))
    
    # Create a ggplot stacked bar plot with filtered data
    # Customize the plot further based on your data and visualization preferences
    plot <- ggplot() +
      geom_bar(data = excess_filtered, aes(x = Month, y = Excess, fill = `Main Practice Area`), stat = "identity") +
      geom_point(data = overall_excess, aes(x = Month, y = Overall_Excess), color = "blue", size = 3, show.legend = FALSE) +
      geom_text(data = overall_excess, aes(x = Month, y = Overall_Excess, label = Overall_Excess), nudge_y = 7, size = 3) +
      geom_line(data = overall_excess, aes(x = Month, y = Overall_Excess, group = 1), color = "darkblue", size = 0.85, show.legend = FALSE) +
      labs(title = "Excess Supply by Main Practice Area",
           x = "Month", y = "Excess Supply") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
    
    # Convert ggplot to plotly
    plot <- ggplotly(plot)
    
    # Add the JavaScript code to the plot using htmlwidgets::onRender
    plot <- htmlwidgets::onRender(plot, js)
    
    print(plot)
  })
```

Comment: That's not very understandable without the full code. Coul you post a *minimal* full app? Also, `input$tabset` has no `names`.

Comment: Added the plot also. The main thing is the removeTab function, and why it is not getting called